# url.action doesn't generate url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass image url and id number to `SaveImage()` function in `DataController` with `@Url.Action()` but it is not working.

I debugged the program and it seems that after the url.action method, a method named Dispose is being activated.

I saw other answers to similar questions but they didn't help me because I already use this: `' '` and not this: `" "` and I didn't use Jquery or Ajax.

my js function:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var uri;

    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {

            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                '<img src="' +
                data_uri +
                '"/>';
            //uri = data_uri;


            var id = obj.id;
            alert("debug 2");
            var url = '@Url.Action("SaveImage","Data")';
            window.location.href = url + '?im_url=' + data_uri + '&id=' + id;

        });
    }
</script>
```

`SaveImage()` method:

```
public ActionResult SaveImage(String im_url, String id)
{
    int x = Int32.Parse(id);
    string s = im_url;
    return View();
}
```

the Dispose function that was created automatically:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {

            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Comment: if Url.Action doesn't generate a URL, what **does** it do? What is the final output you can see in the HTML? (Just use your browser's View Source to see it).

Comment: And where is this Dispose method? On what class is that defined? It looks like it's just getting rid of a database context, so hard to really see how that could be relevant to be honest.

Comment: dispose method is in the data controller and I also don't see how it is relevent.
the url.action method does nothing, what happens is that I stay on the same page as before

Comment: Url.Action doesn't, by itself, change the page. the JavaScript code does that (at whatever time the callback declared inside the snap function gets executed). Url.Action just generates a URL string and injects it into your page. So as I already mentioned, the first thing you need to do is check that the URL it generated was what you expected. If that looks ok, then secondly you need to open your Console and check for any errors in the JavaScript which occur when the callback function is executed (or beforehand)

Comment: but it doesn't generate a url, it goes to the dispose function

Comment: The dispose function will be just occurring at the end of the request. Doesn't it then load the view which contains the above JavaScript (so you can then check the finished Source of the page in your browser, to see the generated URL)? If it doesn't do that, then what **does** it do after it's finished running the Dispose method? Do you get an error or something? (Note: When giving debugging information it's at least as important to say what _is_ happening as it is to say what _isn't_ happening. We can't see your screen.)

Comment: Check your route config. for example, if you remove {id} from MapRoute.All of the Url.actions that have an id to that controller won't be generated.so you have to check your route config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was but I solved it, I moved the line that generates the url outside the webcam function.

from:

```
function take_snapshot() {


Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {

        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
            '<img src="' +
            data_uri +
            '"/>';
        //uri = data_uri;


        var id = obj.id;
        alert("debug 2");
        var url = '@Url.Action("SaveImage","Data")';
        window.location.href = url + '?im_url=' + data_uri + '&id=' + id;

    });
}
```

to:

```
function take_snapshot() {
var url = '@Url.Action("SaveImage","Data")';
        Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {

            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                '<img src="' +
                data_uri +
                '"/>';
            //uri = data_uri;


            var id = obj.id;
            alert("debug 2");
            window.location.href = url + '?im_url=' + data_uri + '&id=' + id;

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your url is not generating fine. Please use this code to generate your url.

```
var link = '@Url.Action("SaveImage","Data", new{ im_url="-1", id="-2"})'.replace("-1",data_uri).replace("-2",id);
window.location.href = link;
```

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.